# what is activate file in flask and what are other activate.bat activate.ps1 and others

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am new to flask, in some tutorial i saw using something like /Scripts/activate in linux and in other tutorial i saw /Scripts/activate.ps1 what are those activate.ps1 activate.bat and how they differ from activate file.

are all those only for activating environment but in different way?

Comment: That's likely for a python virtual environment. Flask doesn't require a python virtual environment, but.... each penv lets you install modules separately. You can run flask (or any number of python packages) in its own virtual environment so that you don't have to worry about conflicting python modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the typical script to activate a conda or venv environment. Best practice is to create a virtual environment (e.g., with conda or venv) specifically for each project, to avoid conflicts, and then activate that environment just before using it.

On Linux, the path is normally `bin/activate`, while `Scripts\activate*` would be normal on Windows.

On Windows, `Scripts\activate.bat` is for a `cmd` shell, while `Scripts\activate.ps1` is for PowerShell.

Comment: so what about activate file without any extension like .bat or .ps1?

Comment: Without extension is for Linux, and probably Mac too.